# Does anyone know how to Associate Automation in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and MTM, I have created a CodedUI test in Visual Studio from recorded steps for a test case, but for the life of me I can't work out how to link the CudedUI test back to the test case in MTM, for visual studio 2010 you did it via the test view window, but I can't find this on 2013, and I can't find any documentation on how to do it on 2013, any ideas would help.

Thanks

Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the solution containing the *CodedUI* test implementation in *Visual Studio*.
2. Open *Test Case* you want to automate in *Visual Studio*.
3. Change to "Associated Automation"
4. Select your *CodedUI* test.

[image]

(It's working the same way with VS2010 and VS2012. Unfortunately I currently can't access to VS2013 installation, but it's working the same way, to my knowledge).